# How to use mongoose with typescript?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, mongoose, mean

I am creating a project on Angular, where use typescript to code server. And I can't get data from DB.

I have model.

```js
import { Document, Schema, Types, model } from "mongoose";

export interface ITopic extends Document {
    title: string,
    questions: Types.ObjectId[]
}

const topicSchema: Schema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    questions: {
        type: [Types.ObjectId],
        required: true,
        default: []
    }
})

export const Topic = model<ITopic>('Topic', topicSchema)
```

Also I have route for topics.

```js
import { Router } from 'express'
import { Topic, ITopic } from '../models/topicModel'

export const topicsRoute = Router()

topicsRoute.get('/all', async (req, res) => {

    const topics : any = await Topic.find()
    console.log(topics);

    if (!topics){
        return res.status(400).json({error: 'Темы не найдены'})
    }

    res.status(200).json(topics)
})
```

And when I want to get all documents of topics collection, I got nothing - [], but why? Of course I have documents in collection - 1 document.

```json
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64a51c6a5e4cc90e2b2fede4"
  },
  "title": "Общие положения",
  "questions": [
    "64a51d1657c8b5f41f80f020"
  ]
}
```

server.ts

```js
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import { userRouter } from './routes/userRoute'
import { topicRoute } from './routes/topicRoute'

dotenv.config({path: './config.env'})
const PORT = process.env.PORT

const app = express()
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())

app.use('/user', userRouter)
app.use('/topic', topicRoute)

app.listen(PORT, () =>{
    mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL || '')
        .then(() => {
            console.log(`Server is running on ports: ${PORT}`)
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    
})
```

Comment: Did you connect to the database?

Comment: did you create the collection manually? If yes, are you sure that the collection name is matching the automatically created one by mongoose?

Comment: could you please add a try catch block around your Topic.find() just to be sure you're not missing an error ? Also, have you checked that your connection to the DB worked ?

Comment: I'm sure db is connected. I have 2 reasons: 
1. Firstly I code server on js and it's worked, but agter I want to code server on ts
2. I alaso try to get data from users colection. And in code I write error if users is null, and when I try to get user, console show error, which I write

Comment: But I can show my server.ts file (show in question). In console I get "Server is runnig..."

Comment: @Emilien try-catch not help. No enteres in catch segment

Comment: If you connected the database, then check which database did you connect using `console.log(mongoose.connection.name)` and which database contains the collection. Make sure it's the same database